# How can I implement star ratings using CakePHP?

Tags: plugins, cakephp-2.0, rating, cakephp-2.x, cakedc

i have find a plugin to implement star ratings using CakePHP https://github.com/CakeDC/ratings 
but i don't know how to use it. i want to have five stars.
 i'm a beginner in the CakePHP. and  I would to calculate for the ratings.
 i use cakphp 2.8.

should i create a table named rating ? 
 how do I calculate for the ratings ?
what should i write in the controller, view and model ?
plz help me 
Thank you in advance for your answers.

Cordially.

Answer (score 0):

First add this component in your controller like this

```
public $helpers = array('Ratings.RatingHelper');
public $components = array(
        'Ratings.Ratings'
    );
```

In your view function

```
$this->set('isRated', $this->{$this->modelClass}->isRatedBy($id, $this->Auth->user('id')));
```

In view.ctp file

```
if ($isRated === false) {
    echo $this->Rating->display(array(
        'item' => $post['Post']['id'],
        'url' => array($post['Post']['id'])
    ));
} else {
    echo __('You have already rated.');
}
```

You can check tutorial file in its docs folder. If have any issue plz let me know

Comment: i want to store the rating in the data base . should i create a table rating ?

Comment: Yes you need to create a table 'ratings' .check config folder -> schema file

Comment: this plugin let me store the rating or i should write a code ?

Comment: You should write a code, you can make  custom code. wait i am creating